# How do I install a newer version of Oracle JDK?

Tags: installation, java, openjdk, jdk, oracle

Using the guide here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux I have installed Oracle's JDK because it has a few features that are not present in OpenJDK.

Now, there some new features released in the Early Access of Oracle's JDK which I need.

I have two questions pertaining to this:

1. How do I completely get rid of Oracle's JDK ?
2. How do I upgrade my current Oracle JDK ?
   Given that my knowledge is limited to the guide, I guess the changes will be after step 9 where I will have to replace `jdk1.7.0_40` with the appropriate version.

Please help me with this =)

Answer (score 1):

You can just download a new version, untar it into /usr/lib/java/ near the old java version and update symlinks by "sudo update-alternatives" like in your tutorial.
And don't forget to change env varible JAVA_HOME to new java directory (/usr/lib/java/< new_version >).

Comment: So, I was right... continue from Step 9 =)